# TikZ arrow tip is drawn with two colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-arrows

This is my code (ConTeXt, but I think that's not relevant here):

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes,calc,arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
  arr/.style = { -{Stealth[width=2mm]} },
  garr/.style = {arr, dashed, draw=green},
  cflow/.style={draw=black,ellipse,text centered,minimum width=1cm}
}

\starttext
  \starttikzpicture
    \node[cflow] (A) {A};
    \node[cflow,right=of A] (E) {E};
    \node[cflow,below right=.35cm and 1.4cm of E] (B) {B};

    \path[arr]
      (A) edge (E)
      (E) edge (B);
    \path[garr]
      (A) edge[bend right] (B);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

The result is:

[image]

Why is the arrow head drawn with both green and black and why do they have different sizes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to page 190 of the manual, stealth arrows are built according to a quadrilateral.

> The *< color >* will apply **both** to any **drawing** and **filling** operations
>   used to construct the path. For instance, even though the Stealth
>   arrow tips looks like a filled quadrilateral, it is actually
>   constructed by drawing a quadrilateral and then filling it in the same
>   color as the drawing (see the fill option below to see the
>   difference).

But if you specify a color for the arrow with the `draw` option, it is only its border that takes on this color. For it to `fill` green, it must also be filled with green.

```
garr/.style = {arr, dashed,draw=green,fill=green},
```

Here, it is enough to indicate the color without specifying draw for it to also fill the arrow.

```
garr/.style = {arr, dashed,green},
```

[image: draw-fill]

here a solution with PDFLatex (I don't use Context, but it's the same).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes,calc,arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
  arr/.style = { -{Stealth[width=2mm]} },
  garr/.style = {arr, dashed,green},
  cflow/.style={draw=black,ellipse,text centered,minimum width=1cm}
}
\begin{document}
%\starttext
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[cflow] (A) {A};
    \node[cflow,right=of A] (E) {E};
    \node[cflow,below right=.35cm and 1.4cm of E] (B) {B};

    \path[arr]
      (A) edge (E)
      (E) edge (B);
    \path[garr]
      (A) edge[bend right] (B);
\end{tikzpicture} 
%\stoptext    

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Thanks! I don't even remember how I ended up using `draw=green` when just `green` suffices.

Comment: There are nearly a thousand different keys with `TikZ`, so the extraordinary thing would be to not forget anything:-)