# TikZ fill using draw color

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-decorations

The following code uses a decorator to add an arrow tip to an edge. Logically, the tip is part of the edge, and so I want it to be colored with the line-color. However, because the tip is rendered using `\fill`, it takes its color from the `fill` parameter. How can I make the color to respond to `draw=red`, and also not respond to `fill=blue`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, crop,border=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\drawArrow}[2]{
    \draw[
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.8 with {%
                \fill (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    ] #1 -- #2;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tikzset{
    pe/.style={
        line width = 1pt,
        decoration={
            show path construction, 
            lineto code={%
                \drawArrow{(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}{(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            closepath code={%
                \drawArrow{(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}{(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    }
}

% Not what I want
\draw[pe, draw = red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);

% Not what I want
\draw[pe, draw = red, fill=blue] (0, 0.25) -- (1, 0.25) -- (1, 0.5) -- (0, 0.5) -- cycle;

% What I want
\draw[pe, red] (0, 0.6) -- (1, 0.6);

% Not what I want
\draw[pe, red, fill=blue] (0, 0.75) -- (1, 0.75) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;

% What I want, simulated
\fill[pe, fill=blue] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;
\draw[pe, red] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplication of this question:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462552/138900

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TikZ arrow tip is drawn with two colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462552/tikz-arrow-tip-is-drawn-with-two-colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `findArrowColor` style, based on [this Georg Sievelson's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460205/91544), picks the current stroke color if such is available, then the current text color if such is available, and black color as the last resort.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, crop,border=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  /tikz/findArrowColor/.style={/utils/exec={%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikz@strokecolor}{}}%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikz@textcolor}{}}%
        {%
            \colorlet{#1}{black}%
        }%
        {\colorlet{#1}{\tikz@textcolor}}%
    }%
    {%
        \colorlet{#1}{\tikz@strokecolor}%
    }%
  }}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\drawArrow}[2]{
    \draw[
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.8 with {%
                \begin{scope}
                    \tikzset{findArrowColor=arrowColor}
                    \fill[fill=arrowColor] (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    ] #1 -- #2;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\tikzset{
    pe/.style={
        line width = 1pt,
        decoration={
            show path construction, 
            lineto code={%
                \begin{scope}[#1]
                \drawArrow{(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}{(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
                \end{scope}
            },
            closepath code={%
                \begin{scope}[#1]
                \drawArrow{(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}{(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
                \end{scope}
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    }
}

\draw[pe, fill = blue] (0, -0.2) -- (1, -0.2);
\draw[pe, draw = red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
\draw[pe, draw = red, fill=blue] (0, 0.25) -- (1, 0.25) -- (1, 0.5) -- (0, 0.5) -- cycle;
\draw[pe, red, fill=blue] (0, 0.75) -- (1, 0.75) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;

\fill[fill=blue] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;
\draw[pe, red] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2

You can make the color of the decoration a parameter of the style.

```
decoration={
    markings, mark=at position 0.8 with {%
        \fill[#1] (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
    }
```

Just call this style `pe=yellow`, by default these style is red.

```
\documentclass[tikz, crop,border=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    pe/.style={
        %line width = 1pt,
        decoration={
            markings, mark=at position 0.8 with {%
                \fill[#1] (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    pe/.default=red
}
% Incorrect
\draw[pe=yellow, draw = red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);

% Incorrect
\draw[pe=black, draw = red, fill=blue] (0, 0.25) -- (1, 0.25) -- (1, 0.5) -- (0, 0.5) -- cycle;

% Correct
\draw[pe, red] (0, 0.6) -- (1, 0.6);

% Incorrect
\draw[pe, red, fill=blue] (0, 0.75) -- (1, 0.75) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;

% Correct, simulated
\fill[pe, fill=blue] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pe default]

#### Update

If I understood correctly, you must specify the color in the decoration.

```
decoration={
            markings, mark=at position 0.8 with {%
                \fill[red] (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
            }
        },
```

[image: decoration]

```
\documentclass[tikz, crop,border=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    pe/.style={
        %line width = 1pt,
        decoration={
            markings, mark=at position 0.8 with {%
                \fill[red] (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
}

% Incorrect
\draw[pe, draw = red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);

% Incorrect
\draw[pe, draw = red, fill=blue] (0, 0.25) -- (1, 0.25) -- (1, 0.5) -- (0, 0.5) -- cycle;

% Correct
\draw[pe, red] (0, 0.6) -- (1, 0.6);

% Incorrect
\draw[pe, red, fill=blue] (0, 0.75) -- (1, 0.75) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;

% Correct, simulated
\fill[pe, fill=blue] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;
\draw[pe, red] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Simply by not specifying `draw=red`, but just `red`

    \draw[pe, red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);

[![red][2]][2]

    \documentclass[tikz, crop,border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        pe/.style={
            decoration={
                markings, mark=at position 0.8 with {%
                    \fill (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
                }
            },
            postaction=decorate
        }
    }
    \draw[pe, red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This modifies the fill color, which I want to control independently for filled polygons.

Comment: Show us an example of its effect.

Comment: I was wrong in that it does not modify the fill color. However, specifying the fill color overrides the color for the arrow tip, which should not happen.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is now, edit your question.

Comment: Added new images. The arrow should respond to setting the draw color, and not respond to setting the fill color.

Comment: No, everything's normal. Read page 190 of the manual.

Comment: I'm not implying there is a bug; I edited again for clarity. I would like it to behave in the way I specify, and am asking how to achieve that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the problem is. Instead, show us what you want to do but can't do it with the current TikZ rules. Have you read page 190?

Comment: I have read page 190, but it is not relevant here. Above I'm showing an image of a polygon filled in blue, with a red line. The decorator is logically attached to the edge, so when I specify fill=blue, I want the arrow tip to preserve the red color, because that is the color of the edge.

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: Specifying the color of the fill in the decorator is the crux of the problem as you noted. But how could it be made to adopt the current line-color, so that it responds to draw=red?

Comment: I just updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Just define a style for the arrow and set it accordingly.

```
\documentclass[tikz, crop,border=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{pearrow/.style={fill},
peset/.code={\tikzset{pearrow/.style={#1}}}}
\newcommand{\drawArrow}[2]{
    \draw[
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.8 with {%
                \path[pearrow] (0, 0.5pt) -- ++ (-0.25, 0.075) -- ++ (0, -0.075) -- cycle;
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    ] #1 -- #2;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tikzset{
    pe/.style={
        line width = 1pt,
        decoration={
            show path construction, 
            lineto code={%
                \drawArrow{(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}{(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            },
            closepath code={%
                \drawArrow{(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)}{(\tikzinputsegmentlast)}
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    }
}


% with peset
\draw[pe, red, fill=blue,peset={fill=red}] (0, 0.75) -- (1, 0.75) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;

% What I want, simulated
\fill[pe, fill=blue] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;
\draw[pe, red] (0, 1.1) -- (1, 1.1) -- (1, 1.35) -- (0, 1.35) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]